# Unity 5.3 - C# -- List<Vector2> How to extract biggest X-value?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm developing a C# script on Unity 5.3. I have a list of Vector2 values and I need to extract the biggest X value in the list. I'm trying to do the following:

```
public List<Vector2> Series1Data;
... //I populate the List with some coordinates
MaXValue = Mathf.Max(Series1Data[0]);
```

However, I get the following errors:

```
error CS1502: The best overloaded method match for `UnityEngine.Mathf.Max(params float[])' has some invalid arguments
error CS1503: Argument `#1' cannot convert `UnityEngine.Vector2' expression to type `float[]'
```

Is there any other way of extracting the biggest X value in the list?

Comment: You probably could try like this:
int xMax = Single.MinValue;
foreach (Vector2 vector in Series1Data)
{
  if (vector.X > xMax)
  {
    xMax = vector.X;
  }
}

Comment: Thank you, I'll try right away @RomanSidorov

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to put a List on a function that can't have that type of variable as parameter.

[Mathf.Max](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Max.html) here you can see which type of parameters it can handle.

This code might do the work:

```
public List<Vector2> Series1Data;
... //I populate the List with some coordinates

MaXValue = Series1Data[0].x; //Get first value
for(int i = 1; i < Series1Data.Count; i++) { //Go throught all entries
  MaXValue = Mathf.Max(Series1Data[i].x, MaXValue); //Always get the maximum value
}
```

Comment: This worked great, and I don't have to define any values. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You can do this via Linq:

```
MaxXValue = Series1Data.Max(v => v.x);
```

This assumes you Series1Data List object is not null or empty.

Answer (score 2):

You probably could try like this:

```
float xMax = Single.MinValue; 
foreach (Vector2 vector in Series1Data)
 {
   if (vector.X > xMax)
   {
     xMax = vector.X; 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to get the maximum Vector itself with your code, instead you want to get the maximum 'x' value of the vector - which is a float instead of a vector; try this code:

```
public List<Vector2> Series1Data;
//I populate the List with some coordinates
MaXValue = Mathf.Max(Series1Data[0].x);
```

EDIT:

I just realised that the Mathf.Max() function takes an array of floats as a parameter - you'll need to separate the 'x' value floats from the vector; perhaps the following may work:

```
public List<Vector2> Series1Data;
//I populate the List with some coordinates
float[] xCoordinates = new float[Series1Data.Count]
for(int i = 0; i < Series1Data.Count; i++)
{
    xCoordinates[i] = Series1Data[i].x;
}
MaXValue = Mathf.Max(xCoordinates);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies within the fact that you are passing a `List<>` of type `Vector2` when `Mathf.Max()` takes an `array` of type float.  Instead of your code, do something like this:

```
public Vector2[] Series1Data;
public float[] Series1DataX;
... //Populate Series1Data with data like this: Series1Data[number] = data;
... //Populate Series1DataX with data like this: Series1DataX[number] = data.x;
MaXValue = Mathf.Max(Series1DataX);
```

So you have two arrays: an array that stores all the `Vector2`s and one that stores the `Vector2`s' X values.

Answer (score 0):

Use like below.

`MaXValue = Mathf.Max(Series1Data[0].x);`

Cause of your error, Series1Data[] is vector2 and MaxValue is float. It's a type conversion errors. And you want x value from Series1Data[].

For getting the max value from the list you have to iterate through all x values and check the larger one with next one and replace current max if it's larger.

Or you can [sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w56d4y5z.aspx) the list ascending and get the first index values as max.

Answer (score 0):

Unity's Mathf.Max only works with float arrays,
you can make a temporary array with all floats to solve it

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class LelExample : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Vector2> Vec2List = new List<Vector2>();
    public float maxX;

    public void Start()
    {
        float[] x; //set temp arrays
        float[] y;

        GetArraysFromVecList(Vec2List, out x, out y); //set the arrays outputting x and y

        maxX = Mathf.Max(x); //Max the x's
    }
    public void GetArraysFromVecList(List<Vector2> list, out float[] x, out float[] y) //My Custom Void
    {
        float[] tx = new float[list.Count]; //Define temporary arrays
        float[] ty = new float[list.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i)
        {
            tx[i] = list[i].x; //Add x to each corrosponding tx
            ty[i] = list[i].y; //Add y to each corrosponding ty
        }
        x = tx; //set the arrays
        y = ty;
    }
}
```

Hope this works :) ~Sid